# Problem connecting to a SQL server database from a ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I get the following error whilst trying to connect from an ASP.NET web application from a particular server to an instance of SQL Server 2005 on a different server.

> An error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to the
>   server.  When connecting to SQL Server
>   2005, this failure may be caused by
>   the fact that under the default
>   settings SQL Server does not allow
>   remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error
>   Locating Server/Instance Specified)

This article lists 5 steps:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

We have eliminated each of these (there is no firewall).

Running the application on a different web server (in the same network) and it can connect to the database.  Similarly, running the database on a different server, and the application can see it.  It appears to be a problem between these two servers.

The problem occurred at random.  It was working one minute, then not, and hasn't been working since.  Nothing was installed or changed (as far as I can work out) on the server.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: can you connect using SQL Management Studio? Have you tried connecting by IP address instead of qualified server name?

Comment: @Xhalent, yes I can connect using via SQL Management Studio (both from the database server, and another server on the same network (although not the web server, it doesn't have management studio)).

Comment: @Xhalent, And if you mean put the IP address in the connection string instead of the name, yes I have tried that.  Thanks.

Comment: what credentials are you using in connection string in the asp.net application? Username/password or windows creds based on the process? If the latter, I'd check what account the app pool is running in - if is the default then that may be your issue. Let me know.

Comment: I am using username/password.  The connection string looks like this:

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=Server9\SQL2005;User Id=U1;Password=P1;Initial Catalog=DB1;

Comment: can you telnet from the webserver to the databse server telnet [servername] 1433

Comment: @Xhalent No I could not.  After some investigation, I tried the IP address again in the connection string and it worked (I must not have restarted the application pool last time).  I feel like an idiot for having wasted all of my morning on this.  If you put something about IP address in the connection string, I shall accept it as an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried connecting using an IP address rather than a qualified server name in the connection string? Sometimes the remote server can not be resolved but the IP address can be, depending on domain/network dns setup.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  It appears this server has recently had its name changed, and that appears to be confusing something somewhere.  Still not quite sure what.  Thanks.